# How to write proper code for Integrity Testing in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

I started testing my code and there I wrote a piece of code that will test that if any duplicate name trying to save in database it will rises Integrity Error.
First I want to see you my Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True,unique=True,
                            validators=[check_valid_characters, check_digit, check_whitespaces])
    working_languages = models.ManyToManyField(ProgrammingLanguage, verbose_name='preferred languages')
    employees = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='number of employees')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[check_whitespaces])
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name='Contact Number', validators=[MinLengthValidator(11),check_valid_mobile_number])
    company_website = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And Test Case You can see below:

```
def test__when_company_name_duplicate__should_raise_an_error(self):
        ob1 = Company(name='XYZ',employees='12',address='XYz',contact_number='01784009080',company_website='https://stackoverflow.com/')
        ob2 = Company(name='XYZ',employees='13',address='XcYz',contact_number='01784009081',company_website='https://stackoverflow.com/new')

        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            ob1.save()
            ob2.save()
```

After I ran my Testcase the error I am getting is:

### >>FAIL: test__when_company_name_duplicate__should_raise_an_error (testapp.tests.MyTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anik/Works/assignment/task/testapp/tests.py", line 73, in test__when_company_name_duplicate__should_raise_an_error
    ob2.save()
AssertionError: IntegrityError not raised

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,It works for me:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

def test_produces_integrity_error_on_deplicate_name(self):
        Company.objects.create(name='XYZ',employees='12',address='XYz',contact_number='01784009080',company_website='https://stackoverflow.com/')
        self.assertRaises(IntegrityError,Company.objects.create,name='XYZ',employees='13',address='XcYz',contact_number='01784009081',company_website='https://stackoverflow.com/new')
```